# How to zip arrays in Python but keep the remainder?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

So given two arrays, two different lengths how would I combine them so that the sums would be in the resulting array. I can do this if the array is the same length using the zip function but I need the remaining array instead of just returning [4]. The other strategy I was thinking was finding the difference in length then appending the remainder but I don't know if this the optimal solution. I'm trying to solve a binary tree merging problem and this was my first idea for a solution.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3]
>> zipfunction(a,b)
[4,2,3]
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `itertools` has a *lot* of goodies in it, and you should almost consider it like a part of builtins. That is, learn those functions because you often will re-invent them in less efficient ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.zip_longest`

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [3]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(map(sum, zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)))
[4, 2, 3]
```